# what does recursive partitioning create 2^n combinations from n levels of data?

Tags: r, recursion, partitioning, combinatorics, random-forest

When running a random forest, it won't allow over 32 levels in a single variable because it results in 2^n combinations / partitions of data. I figured it would follow the classic combinatorics equation of n!/k!(n-k)! for n choose k. Can anyone explain why this is? For example, if I were to have 4 levels in a variable it partitions to 2^4=16, where I would suspect it should be 16/4=4.

I suspect this is due to the recursive partitioning going on inside the decision trees which make up the larger random forest.

Comment: What software are you using, and what error are you seeing?   Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, let me know how i can clarify! I am using R to build a predictive model. The error is that the model will run incredibly long, or more likely run out of random access memory. My question is trying to understand the theoretical math/computer science behind recursive partitioning with large levels of data in a single variable.

Comment: Please show your code then.   There is not a theoretical reason why an algorithm defined for all `n` would have a bit-limited input size.  That's an implementation detail.   You need to show the implementation, or what you are trying to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you've confused two cases.  You're looking at "How many ways can I choose a given number, **k**, items from a set of **n** items?"  The actual question is "How many ways can I pick a set of items from **n** items?"

The second question is the summation of solutions to the first, for k = 0 to n.
This sum is 2^n.

Another way to look at it is the presence or absence of any given element in your chosen set.  With two choices for each element, we have 2^n total possibilities.

Here's an illustration: let's just take the set {1, 2, 3, 4}.

Case 1: how many ways can I choose k=2 elements from this set?

```
1 2
1   3
1     4
  2 3
  2   4
    3 4
```

which is, indeed, 4! / (2! 2!) = 6 possibilities

However, when we look at total partitions for all values of k, we get

```
. . . .   (empty set)
      4
    3
    3 4
  2
  2   4
  2 3
  2 3 4
1
1     4
1   3
1   3 4
1 2
1 2   4
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

which is 2^4 = 16 choices.  Note that this is also the summation over different values of k: 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1

Comment: This is closely related to Stirling numbers of the second kind (depending on which partitions you consider valid for the purposes of the tree algorithm), if the OP wants more math heavy reading.

Comment: Ah yes, partitioning will create every subset of a given set! Thanks for the very clear answer Prune. Also I love heavy math reading joran, thanks for the idea!